# How to set permission PUBLIC for GET method and ADMIN for POST method in Django REST framework API

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

How to set permission PUBLIC for GET method and  ADMIN for POST method in Django REST framework API?

Answer (score 1):

In your permissions.py (create if not exists)

```
class MyPermisssion(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS or request.user.is_stuff:
            return True
        return False
```

In your views.py

```
 class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (MyPermisssion,)

  ...
```

More about permissions: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/