# How to set different permissions for GET and POST methods with ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to set `IsAuthenticated` permission for `GET` and `IsTeamLeader` permission for `POST` with `ListCreateAPIView` and `ModelSerializer`, but without having a unique permission that check the request method in `has_permission`, as suggested in these questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158273/how-to-set-permission-public-for-get-method-and-admin-for-post-method-in-django) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085003/unable-to-post-with-listcreateapiview).

How could I do that ?

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class ManagerListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Manager.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ManagerSerializer


class IsTeamLeader(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if Manager.objects.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists():
            return Manager.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk).is_team_leader


class ManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    fields = serializers.JSONField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Passwords must match.')
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = {
            key: value for key, value in validated_data.items()
            if key not in ('password1', 'password2')
        }
        data['password'] = validated_data['password1']
        user = self.Meta.model.objects.create_user(**data)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'role', 'is_team_leader', 'password1', 'password2', 'fields')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role', 'is_team_leader', 'address', 'contact')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `get_permission` ftn in your views class, if the method is `GET` you can return your expected permission class else you can return default it would be for `POST` method e.g:

```
    def get_permissions(self):
        self.permission_classes = [IsTeamLeader]
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            self.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        return super(ManagerListView, self).get_permissions()
```

let me know if it helps you.

As above will block the Browsable form in html view you can add one tricky condition and update the ftn. (not recommended)

```
    def get_permissions(self):
        self.permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        if self.request.method == "POST" and self.request.data:
            self.permission_classes = [IsTeamLeader]
        return super(ManagerListView, self).get_permissions()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested your code and it throws `'BasePermissionMetaclass' object is not iterable
`

Comment: Thanks @Usman, it's exactly what I wanted and works perfectly

Comment: @Florent - If you want to use html view as with above permissions, this would be tricky. I'll update the answer for that. But I would not recommend that.

Comment: I thought my user has the Team Leader privilege but it was not the case. With a privileged user the HTML is still available to POST content, so your initial answer fit both the browsable and the non-browsable API